# Using CommVault to backup a NAS without NDMP

Tags: backup, storage, optimization, tape

We have CommVault Simpana 9.0.0 build 84 currently installed and configured on our backup server that is equipped with both a magnetic array and a tape library. I am trying to find a way to backup one of our Buffalo TeraStation TS-RX400TL NAS devices (firmware 1.50) using the NAS iDataAgent or by some other means that does not require another computer with a CommVault agent to sit in between the Buffalo TeraStation NAS and the CommVault. Everything that I am reading in the Books Online (9.0.0) website and in the books Common Technology Engine and CommVault Storage Policies seems to point me in the direction of configuring NDMP (Network Data Management Protocol) settings for the NAS iDataAgent in the CommCell or on a computer with the NAS iDataAgent sitting in between the CommVault and the PSTNAS. Is there a way to do this with a NAS that does not support NDMP? We were sold on the fact that the CommVault can do this when we purchased the solution, but how to specifically configure this since it wasn’t done during our initial configuration is what has been eluding me.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to mount the shares on your Backup Server (aka the Media Agent in Commvault) and just backup them up as if they were local drives.

Comment: What we ended up doing was using one of our already backed up file server's iDataAgent to backup the NAS device using a UNC path. The DeDupeDB is stored on the machine with the iDA, but this is ok since it is better than nothing. We just created a new subclient for the NAS at the defaultBackupSet level and added it to a pre-existing schedule. Thanks a bunch for your input as it got us on the right track!

Comment: No worries. That approach is equally valid and I should have mentioned that in my answer.

You might want to have a look at where the DeDupeDB lives depending on the I/O and CPU load it produces on the machine with the iDA.

Answer (score 0):

What we ended up doing was using one of our already backed up file server's iDataAgent to backup the NAS device using a UNC path. The DeDupeDB is stored on the machine with the iDA, but this is ok since it is better than nothing. We just created a new subclient for the NAS at the defaultBackupSet level and added it to a pre-existing schedule.